# Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source in safari,chrome, Phonegap build

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, github, pdf.js

I try to render the pdf document with the help of pdf.js in Jquery Mobile application.
For testing I used the browsers like FFox, Chrome, Safari. The source come from remote server using Ajax call. So the pdf.js not supported for URL that contains remote server path. So I used Base64 method here. It was worked with FFox, But not in Chrome/Safari

The ajax call is

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: surl,
            data: dataString,
            processData: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

```
            fileData = response.Response[0].result.report_stream;
            var base64String = base64ArrayBuffer(fileData);
            var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64String;

            localStorage.setItem("PrintDoc", pdfAsDataUri);
```

And I set the URI in viewer.js file

```
         var DEFAULT_URL = localStorage.getItem("PrintDoc");
```

This method works foe me in FFox, But not in Chrome/Safari

Safari shows the error like

```
PDF.js v1.0.712 (build: 6969ed4)
```

Message: Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/....  //shortened

Please advice me to solve this issue..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=base64+pdf.js responses might help